# No se pudo instalar el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver 0.4.3'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, selenium, nuget, chromedriver

Estoy intentando instalar el paquete `'AsyncChromeDriver 0.4.3'` mediante `NuGet` pero a la hora de terminar la instalación lanza este error:

> No se pudo instalar el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver 0.4.3'. Está
>   intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto que tiene
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' como destino, pero el paquete no
>   contiene referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido compatibles
>   con dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en contacto con
>   el autor del paquete.

Y la traza es la siguiente:

```
Intentando recopilar información sobre la dependencia para el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver.0.4.3' respecto al proyecto 'Controller', con el destino '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
La recopilación de información de dependencia tardó 1,86 sec
Intentando resolver las dependencias para el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver.0.4.3' con DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
La resolución de información de dependencia tardó 0 ms
Resolviendo acciones para instalar el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver.0.4.3'
Se resolvieron las acciones para instalar el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver.0.4.3'
Recuperando paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver 0.4.3' de 'nuget.org'.
Recuperando paquete 'AsyncWebDriver 1.3.2' de 'nuget.org'.
Recuperando paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient 0.1.10' de 'nuget.org'.
Recuperando paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1' de 'nuget.org'.
Recuperando paquete 'WebSocket4Net 0.14.1' de 'nuget.org'.
Agregando el paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' se agregó a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' se agregó a 'packages.config'
'Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1' se instaló correctamente en Controller
Agregando el paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient.0.1.10' a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient.0.1.10' se agregó a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient.0.1.10' se agregó a 'packages.config'
'IAsyncWebBrowserClient 0.1.10' se instaló correctamente en Controller
Agregando el paquete 'AsyncWebDriver.1.3.2' a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'AsyncWebDriver.1.3.2' se agregó a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'AsyncWebDriver.1.3.2' se agregó a 'packages.config'
'AsyncWebDriver 1.3.2' se instaló correctamente en Controller
Agregando el paquete 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' se agregó a la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' se agregó a 'packages.config'
'WebSocket4Net 0.14.1' se instaló correctamente en Controller
Error en la instalación. Revirtiendo...
El paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver.0.4.3 : AsyncWebDriver [1.3.2, ), Newtonsoft.Json [11.0.1, ), WebSocket4Net [0.14.1, )' no existe en el proyecto 'Controller'
El paquete 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' se quitó de 'packages.config'
El paquete 'AsyncWebDriver.1.3.2 : IAsyncWebBrowserClient [0.1.10, )' se quitó de 'packages.config'
El paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient.0.1.10 : Newtonsoft.Json [10.0.3, )' se quitó de 'packages.config'
El paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' se quitó de 'packages.config'
El paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver.0.4.3 : AsyncWebDriver [1.3.2, ), Newtonsoft.Json [11.0.1, ), WebSocket4Net [0.14.1, )' no existe en la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
Quitando el paquete 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'WebSocket4Net.0.14.1' se quitó de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
Quitando el paquete 'AsyncWebDriver.1.3.2 : IAsyncWebBrowserClient [0.1.10, )' de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'AsyncWebDriver.1.3.2 : IAsyncWebBrowserClient [0.1.10, )' se quitó de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
Quitando el paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient.0.1.10 : Newtonsoft.Json [10.0.3, )' de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'IAsyncWebBrowserClient.0.1.10 : Newtonsoft.Json [10.0.3, )' se quitó de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
Quitando el paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
El paquete 'Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1' se quitó de la carpeta 'C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\VisualBet\packages'
La ejecución de acciones de NuGet tardó 2,32 sec
No se pudo instalar el paquete 'AsyncChromeDriver 0.4.3'. Está intentando instalar este paquete en un proyecto que tiene '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2' como destino, pero el paquete no contiene referencias de ensamblado o archivos de contenido compatibles con dicho marco. Para obtener más información, póngase en contacto con el autor del paquete.
Tiempo transcurrido: 00:00:04.1911481
========== Finalizado ==========
```

En la solución están instalados los siguientes paquetes:

- Selenium.WebDriver v3.11.2
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver v2.38.0

Mi versión de .NET Framework es 4.7.1.

Adjunto imagen del Administrador de paquetes Nuget:

[image: Error al instalar el paquete]

Comment: estas seguro que usas .net 4.7.1? no intentaste pasarlo a la version de .net algo mas estandar para ver si asi agrega la libreria? puede que al ser una version de framework muy nuevo no lo este detectando como soportado por la libreria

Answer (score 1):

Tenía instalado en el equipo la versión .NET Framework 4.7.1, pero la plataforma de destino del proyecto era la 4.5.2. Al final lo único que he hecho es ir a:

**Explorador de soluciones > Seleccionar el proyecto donde se va a instalar el paquete > Botón derecho > Propiedades**

Y en **Aplicación** seleccionar la plataforma de destino .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Igualmente muchas gracias por el comentario.

Adjunto imagen para facilitar la ayuda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]